# How to print elements of a list in python and number them starting from 1?

Tags: python

I have a list with 10 names and I'm storing a random sample of 6 names from that list into another list. I'm trying to display the 2nd list as a table along with the index number. How can I get my index to start from 1 using the code below?

```
import random
list1 = [name1,name2,name3,name4,name5,name6,name7,name8,name9,name10]
list2 = random.sample(list1,6)
for i in range(0,len(list2)):
    print(i,list2[i])
```

Using above, the index starts at 0 but I need it to start at 1. If set the for loop range to start with 1, and set len(list2)+1, I get index out of bounds error.

Comment: Because the index represents a week

Answer (score 2):

Use `enumerate()` with the optional `start` argument:

```
for i, name in enumerate(list2, start=1):
    print(i, name)
```

Answer (score 1):

In `range(0, len(list2))`, 0 is the starting index. If you wish to start at 1, just change that value

```
import random
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
list2 = random.sample(list1, 6)
for i in range(1, len(list2) + 1):
    print(i, list2[i - 1])
```

You can also use `enumerate`

Comment: I tried the same approach. That wouldn't do it because I need to go up to 6. And my sample size can only be 6.

Comment: my bad, i edited the answer

Comment: Thank you, I guess that's what I was attempting to do in my code initially.